# Move files from S3 subfolder to the S3 bucket root

Tags: amazon-s3, cmd, automation, teamcity, aws-cli

I need to move all files of a subfolder to it s3 bucket root.

Right now I'm using cmd AWS CLI

`aws s3 mv s3:\\testbucket\testsubfolder\testsubfolder2\folder s3:\\testbucket\`

My main issue is that the subfolder "folder" changes every day after a TeamCity run. It is ay way to know if there is a new folder inside "testsubfolder2", and copy its content to the S3bucket root?

I want to automate this, as every day we run reports and are stored in an S3, but TeamCity create a project folder tree, and we need all the files on the S3 root

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that your requirements are: "Move all files under `s3:\\testbucket\testsubfolder\testsubfolder2\`, including those in subfolders, to `s3:\\testbucket\`?" What should happen if there are multiple files with the same name, but in different subfolders? Should they overwrite each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a Lambda when a file is uploaded in this testsubfolder2 directory.

Check this tutorial from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Be careful with your S3 rules because you can create a loop and increase your billing because AWS S3 MV uses COPY and DELETE behind the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to configure lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that will move any objects in a given Prefix (and sub-folders under that Prefix) into the root of the bucket. (Actually, it copies the object and then deletes it.)

```py
import boto3

BUCKET = 'stack-move'
PREFIX = 'foo1/foo2/'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET)

for object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=PREFIX):
    print(object.key)
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': BUCKET,
        'Key': object.key
    }
    target_key = object.key[object.key.rfind('/')+1:] # Get just the name after the last slash

    # Copy the object
    target = bucket.Object(target_key) 
    target.copy(copy_source)

    # Delete the object
    object.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks John, I tested your example, and also worked for me.